# Does memcache retain information until flush?

Tags: php, memcached

The question title basically says it all..

If I perform:

```
$Cache = new Memcache;

$Cache->connect('HOST');


$Cache->set('Information', 'array(
 "Testing" => "Value,
 "Anther_Test" => "Another Value"

)');
```

and leave the information there, would the information be flushed/deleted after an interval?

or will it retain within the server until I call:

```
$Cache->flush();
```

Comment: That depends on the configuration. I suggest you read a bit what memchached is, how it works and how it can be configured.

Comment: `'array(
 "Testing" => "Value,
 "Anther_Test" => "Another Value"

)'` --- this is a reeeeeally weird value

Comment: @hakre I have the current windows binary, which does not let me access or even see the configuration files.. Let alone modify them

Comment: @zerkms This is a demonstration

Comment: I didn't mean the configure command (albeit it would be interesting for you to actually know about it for your binary perhaps), but more the runtime configuration: https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewConfiguringServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @hakre wrote in a comment plus you should get how to use cache.
Cache is not a date storage, it is a cache. You should never relay on what is there and what is not.
Typically you have a limit of a cache size and when it gets full it purges old values.

Typical usage case:

```
function get_something() {
    $Cache = new Memcache;
    $something = $Cache->get('something');
    if ($something === false) {
        $something = //get from db, prepare or whatever
        $Cache->set('something', $something);
    }
    return $something;
}
```

TLDR; no